# Why doesn't while work in the same shell script as find?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have the following code, it needs to find all the files greater the 10 kilobytes and move them into another directory:

```
read mam
find "$mam" -type f -size +10k > size.txt
while read line
do
    mv "$line" /home/patakinorbert/Desktop/prk1
done < size.txt
```

Comment: Welcome! You can improve this question by adding what you expect to happen, what you observe happening, and what you have tried so far. This will both make the question more helpful to others as well as increase the chances that you get a helpful answer yourself.

Comment: Expanding on @user1794469's comments, if you to want know why your script didn't work, make sure you include enough information so others can reproduce the problem you had.  Simply saying that something "doesn't work" is not sufficient.  We need to know exactly what happened including all error messages.

Comment: actually i coped the whole script into another .sh file and it worked after that, i don't know what could be the problem before. The error was that it just printed the files was bigger then 10 kilobytes

Comment: @Norbi You said "The error was that it just printed the files was bigger then 10 kilobytes".  What error?  We can't answer the _actual question_ if we don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a shell script.  A single `find` command will both search for files and move them:

```
read -r mam
find "$mam" -type f -size +10k -exec mv {} /home/patakinorbert/Desktop/prk1 \;
```

The words between `-exec` and `\;` are a command that is executed for every file found where `{}` is replaced by the name of the found file.

In a Linux system, such as your Ubuntu, or any system that uses GNU tools, a more efficient version of this command is:

```
read -r mam
find "$mam" -type f -size +10k -exec mv -t /home/patakinorbert/Desktop/prk1 +
```

This is more efficient because it moves several files using one invocation of `mv`.

Comment: thank you for you fast answer, yeah maybe i should read the man a bit more carefully next time :D